# Can we find the duplicate of a particular file across the system using python

Tags: python, file, duplicates

I am Newbie to use OS and sys and file functions in python, I am trying to get the **duplicate file across the system for a particular given file using Python**. On referring the internet, I have tried filecompare(filecmp) function, in where I get the duplicate files in the particular directory.  But I need to find the  duplicate files across the system.  Is there any idea?

Comment: Do you have a compelling reason to write your own software for this? Doing it well requires a bunch of optimizations (like comparing sizes and beginning and ending blocks only to rule out possible duplicates so you only compare in full the smallest possible number of files).

Comment: In general, it's much better to use software written by someone who has already done all that work instead of reinventing the wheel yourself. Something used by thousands of people over the course of years will also have fewer bugs than an implementation that's completely brand new.

Comment: And if you _do_ want to do it yourself, that's arguably too large/broad an effort to be a good Stack Overflow question. Start by looking at how something like `fdupes` works, try reimplementing each piece in Python, and come back here and ask a more specific question when you get stuck (if that sticking point isn't already in our knowledge base to start with).